# Solid angle of a pyramid

Tags: solid-geometry, solid-angle

Suppose I have a rectangular pyramid. I partition the dihedral angle between a fixed pair of opposite faces into three parts and thereby obtain three sub-pyramids (within the original one). Consider the sum of the solid angles subtended at the vertex by these sub-pyramids. Is it equal or not to the solid angle subtended by the original pyramid at the vertex ? Please explain.

Comment: (signed) angles are additive, so it should be yes. Can you explain why you think it might potentially be no?

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denote the dihedral angles between opposite faces of the original pyramid and $\alpha=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\alpha_{3}$, then the solid angle of the original pyramid is $\Omega = 4\sin^{-1}(\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{\beta}{2})$ whereas the solid angle of a sub pyramid is $\Omega_{i}=4\sin^{-1}(\sin\frac{\alpha_{i}}{2}\sin\frac{\beta}{2})$. So it seems that $\Omega\neq\Omega_{1}+\Omega_{2}+\Omega_{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the solid angles is equal to the total solid angle. The apparent contradiction with your formula  follows from the fact that it only works for a straight pyramid, and your subpyramides are not straight. Observe that an oblique pyramid with the same height and base subtends a smaller solid angle. The more oblique, the lesser the angle.

Comment: I assume by staight pyramid you mean a right pyramid whose vertex is directly above the centre of its base. Is there any formula for calculating the solid angle of a non-right or oblique pyramid in terms of its dihedral angles ? Please provide any reference, if possible. Also can you explain how the sum of the solid angles is equal to the total solid angle ? Intuitively, it seems so.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by a straight pyramid. I did not know the formula you used so I googled it and read the proof on some site. In the proof, the pyramid was clearly straight, as the base they took a rectangle centered at the origin and the vertex at $(0,0,h)$. I do not know how hard it is to get a formula for an oblique pyramid. The reason why the sum of angles is equal to the total angle is the following. By definition, you have to consider a sphere centered at the vertex, then you extend the lateral faces until they intersect the sphere.

Comment: The region defined on the sphere by those intersections has some area $S$ and the solid angle is just $S/R^2$ where $R$ is the radius of the sphere. It seems clear that the union of the regions defined on the sphere by the sub pyramids  is the region defined by the original pyramid (and they are disjoint).

Comment: Here is an idea how to find the formula for an oblique pyramid. Draw a plane containing the altitude and perpendicular to the base. Assume the projection of the vertex on the base is inside the base for now. Then your pyramid is decomposed into two pyramids, each of them is half of a straight pyramid so you can use your formula. Not clear if the final result can be expressed in terms of the original dihedral angles only because some parameter measuring the skewness of the pyramid should enter the formula.